# Read a file in parts, continue after the last read part

Tags: c++, file-io, iteration

I've been googling this for some time now to no avail and I am not even sure if there is a name for this.

My use case is: I have a big file that contains blocks of text that should be independently processed. They are all listed in the file one after the other and separated with a delimiter. I would like to read that file block by block and do some operations on the read block and then read the next block. Something like iterating through a file, but not reading all at once to memory. I have java code that does that through some kind of BlockGen class that implements iterable interface and reads the file from previously read position when client code needs it, but I am very not sure how to implement this in C++ properly.

Any help appreciated. And yeah, it's not homework!

Comment: Are the blocks fixed size? How are you used to reading files in C++?

Comment: They are enclosed in some kind of a delimiting line so I know where they start and end. I would like to encapsulate file reading into a separate function/class so that all the getline stuff is not in the block processing function. Ideally, block processing function would just say blockgen.getNextBlock() or smth like that.

Comment: Maybe you should include some sample file showing the delimiters. You can use memory-mapped-files, or some buffering (read something ahead) to get each line from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed block sizes, you can use `ifstream::read`

In your case, it won't be too hard to roll your own `BlockGen`:

Given a definition of `Block` e.g. a `std::vector<std::string>`, and a class (with suitable though given to copy constructors etc)

```
class BlockGen
{
    public:
    //boilerplate constructors, taking delimiter between blocks
    // opening input etc, etc

    Block getNextBlock()
    {
        Block block;
        std::string line;
        while( std::getline(input, line)  && line!=delimiter)
        {
            block.push_back(line);
        }
        return block;
    }

    private:
    std::ifstream input;
    std::string delimiter;
};
```

Comment: I think this is it, just have a private member of ifstream type that will "remember" where it should continue reading. I was wondering if that was clean enough..

Comment: It's "clean" in the sense if anything crashes the file gets closed. You may need to jig around the lines you ignore if there are two delimiters per block, but hopefully this was enough to get you started.

Comment: yeah i am not very familiar with that. so if smth crashes, the file will get closed? other than that, yes, this is what i was looking for. thanks.

Comment: Yes :-) RAII. The destructor closed the file. So, in stack unwinding it will get tidied up.